# How to extract only the last value of a variable in pine script

Tags: pine-script

i would like to extract the last value (current value) of my atr in order to base my strategy on the "atr_current". But it seems there is no such last.value function. Could someone provide help ?

atr100 = ta.atr(100)

atr_current = ***last_value***(atr100)

plot(atr_current)

atr100 is a series of values. I want to extract only the last value of the indicator (since it is displayed at far right of the indicator i assume i can extract) and get rid of the previous. is there a function or a way to do that ?

Comment: That is the default behavior for `ta.atr()`.

Comment: but i only want the last value not all the series

Answer (score 0):

When you refer to `atr100` in calculations, it's last value will be used.

Or, if you want to store the atr value in a variable when a condition happens, you can do the following.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My Script")
atr100 = ta.atr(100)

var my_atr = 0.0

if (high >= ta.highest(high, 5))    // Update the atr value if price makes a new high within last five bars
    my_atr := atr100

plot(atr100, color=color.green)
plot(my_atr, color=color.red)
```

See the red line:
[image]